# StartIntentOnResult restart activity

Tags: android

it's my first Android Project and I have some trouble. I have a main activity which is my launcher activity also.

I do two IntentOnResult to get informations from other activities (a Bluetoothcheck and a Search for Beacons). But if I get the result of the second intent it also execute first one. It looks like it restart the hole activity.

How can I "switch" between activities? Marking it as launchmode single Instance doesn't work.

What is my mistake?

Here is my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static int REQUEST_ID_BluetoothCheck = 1;
public static int REQUEST_ID_MonitoringActivity = 1;

public static Button SearchBeacons = null;

//Result der Beacon Suche
public String UUID;
private String Major;
private String Minor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Check aufrufen um Bluetooth zu prüfen
    Intent intentCheckBluetooth = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BluetoothCheck.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentCheckBluetooth, REQUEST_ID_BluetoothCheck);

    SearchBeacons = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SearchBeacons);
    //Button klick erkennen und MonotoringActivity starten
    SearchBeacons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intentStartSearch = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MonitoringActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentStartSearch, REQUEST_ID_MonitoringActivity);
        }
    });

    //Todo Links über Json holen für KIS/ PACS

}

//Methode für die Antwort einer anderen Activity
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID_BluetoothCheck) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetoothcheck erfolgreich durchgeführt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetoothcheck war nicht erfolgreich. Die App funktioniert deshalb nicht und wurde beendet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID_MonitoringActivity){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent IntentBackToMain = getIntent();
            Bundle bundle = IntentBackToMain.getExtras();

            if(bundle != null) {

                UUID = bundle.getString("UUID");
                Major = bundle.getString("Major");
                Minor = bundle.getString("Minor");

            }
        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Beacon suche war nicht erfolgreich. Bitte Prüfen Sie ob sich ein Beacon in der Nähe befindet und probieren es gegebenenfalls nochmal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

__________Update:

In the answer class it looks like:

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("UUID", (String) beacons.iterator().next().getId1().toString());
result.putExtra("Major", (String) beacons.iterator().next().getId2().toString());
result.putExtra("Minor", (String) beacons.iterator().next().getId3().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

in the main class:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID_MonitoringActivity){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            if(bundle != null) {

                UUID = bundle.getString("UUID");
                Major = bundle.getString("Major");
                Minor = bundle.getString("Minor");
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Beacon suche war nicht erfolgreich. Bitte Prüfen Sie ob sich ein Beacon in der Nähe befindet und probieren es gegebenenfalls nochmal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the same request codes for both of the intents as they are used to identify the result in `onActivityResult`:

```
public static int REQUEST_ID_BluetoothCheck = 1;
public static int REQUEST_ID_MonitoringActivity = 2;
```

Another thing that could possibly be wrong:
To finish the Activities you started with `startActivityForResult`, just use `finish()` in them, don't use another Intent for calling your main Activity. If you wan't to send data to your main Activity, call `setResult` with a new intent containing the data before finishing the activity.

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("key", someValue);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

Also, instead of getting the intent like this:

```
Intent IntentBackToMain = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = IntentBackToMain.getExtras();
```

Just use the intent you are provided with in the `onActivityResult` method:

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
```

Comment: Ok I changed it. But the result is same!

Comment: Did you leave the launch mode as default, or do you still use another setting for it? onCreate should not be called when returning from another activity, when using the default launch mode.

Comment: How do you finish the other activities?

Comment: - Launch mode is set by default

- I resume to main activity with a new intent. For example like that:

       Intent IntentBackToMain= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ´MainActivity.class);
startActivity(IntentBackToMain);

Comment: Is the data only missing, or is the bundle itself null?

Comment: I updated the code in the question. I think it's better to see there.

How can I test it? I tried to made a toast there but nothing happens...

Comment: Stop!! I have to correct it! You solve my problem! I made a mistake with a wrong intent in code because i tried to solve it on my own!

Much thanks! :) It's working!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: As you seem to be new here: You can set an answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark to the left side of the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/tour